# dropping columns from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 dataframes and I want to drop certain columns from them. I tried for loop, something like this -

```
dataframes =[af,bf,cf,df,ef,ff,gf]
for col in dataframes:
  print col.head(1)
  col = col.drop(col.columns[[0,2]],axis=1)
  print col.head(1)
```

I know the approach is wrong. How to do that without doing it repetitively ?

Answer (score 1):

consider the list of dataframes `dataframes`

```
dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1], B=[2], C=[3])) for _ in range(4)]
```

Use `drop` and `inplace=True`

```
for d in dataframes:
    d.drop(['B'], 1, inplace=True)

for d in dataframes:
    print(d)

   A  C
0  1  3
   A  C
0  1  3
   A  C
0  1  3
   A  C
0  1  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is correct if need drop columns by positions, also is possible use `list comprehension`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

df1 = df*10
dataframes = [df,df1]

#get changed list of df
dataframes = [df.drop(df.columns[[0,2]],axis=1) for df in dataframes]
print (dataframes)
[   B  D  E  F
0  4  1  5  7
1  5  3  3  4
2  6  5  6  3,     B   D   E   F
0  40  10  50  70
1  50  30  30  40
2  60  50  60  30]

#original not changed
print (df1)
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0  10  40  70  10  50  70
1  20  50  80  30  30  40
2  30  60  90  50  60  30
```

---

```
#get changed all df inplace, operation return `None`, so output is _
_ = [df.drop(df.columns[[0,2]],axis=1, inplace=True) for df in dataframes]
print (df1)
    B   D   E   F
0  40  10  50  70
1  50  30  30  40
2  60  50  60  30
```

and your solution need not assign, but `inplace=True`:

```
for col in dataframes:
  print (col.head(1))
  col.drop(col.columns[[0,2]],axis=1, inplace=True)
  print (col.head(1))

print (df1)
    B   D   E   F
0  40  10  50  70
1  50  30  30  40
2  60  50  60  30
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop dataframes using column index, simply use
`df.drop(df.columns[[0, 2, 5]], axis=1)`

Note: Here I am passing index as 0,2, and 5. The df.columns is zero-based pd.Index